# How to Copy or Extend Condition Formating from Worksheet Template using Epplus

Tags: c#, epplus

I have `.xmls` template file, where is in the first column (Column A), where I have some example data and specified conditional formatting (Rules for A1, and for A3).

I am using this template and dynamically I am adding new columns( maybe hundreds of columns).

Every time I copy the range of the first column and inserting it into a new column. Formatting and styling are copied automatically, that is okay.

However, what I want to do is also copy CONDITIONAL FORMATING specify on the first column. (Make a copy of rules for B1 and B3 or extend existing rule for these Columns)

Is there any way, how to:

1. Copy conditional formatting rule from the first column and paste it on the n-th column?
2. Or is there way, how to extend Address of existing conditional formatting rule?

```
foreach (var condition in ws.ConditionFormating)
{
   condition.Address.Adress += " B1 B3";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the range of the Conditional Formatting:

```
condition.Address = new ExcelAddress("C4:C8,G1:G3");
```

Separate the Ranges with Commas. As you have more than one formatting, you have to distinguish between formatting rules - the easiest way is by their priority:

```
if(condition.Priority == 2)
    condition.Address = new ExcelAddress("C4:C8,G1:G3");
```

It would be more logical of course to tell them apart by their ranges, but I am afraid, there is no EPPlus function to test if two ranges intersect. But you could test if the `Address.Address` begins with `A1` or `A3` ...

***Attention:*** If you read the `Adress.Address` as set above, you get back `"C4:C8 G1:G3"` (Space, not Comma for addresses with more than one range). So if you want to work with this you have to do `condition.Address.Address.Replace(' ',',')` . This seems to be inconsistent within EPPlus.

[API Documentation](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelAddress/P/Address)

[Adressing Sample](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Addressing-a-worksheet)

[Sample cs file for conditional formatting](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample14.cs)